# Why do Ratios not carry over from Xlsx to CSV format

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have an XLSX file that we have output from SAS. The column in question are results from an assay that result in a titer ratio, "NEG" or "Not Assessed". In the XLSX file the column format is "Text".

When I save as and select ANY of the options for CSV the resulting file has a column with several of the ratios changed to decimals. Only ratios of 1:25600 and values of NEG and Not Assessed stay consistent.

We need this to be in a CSV file to upload to our partners portal. Is there a work around?

In then picture provided the XLSX file is on the left and the resulting CSV file is on the right.
[See HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWUOD.png)

Comment: Open your CSV file in some other text editor, like Notepad. What do you see? Or, *import* the CSV file into Excel and specify that column as text? In other words, Excel is often very unhelpful when it comes to CSV files.

Comment: I have already tried to specify that the column is text, general, custom, special and nothing changes the CSV result. If I open the file in WordPad the information is structured the way we want it. But opening the CSV in excel shows numbers as decimals.

Comment: You're likely not *importing* the CSV file in Excel. You can't just open the CSV file, you have to import it. Excel is horrible with CSV files. But there's no real issue here. The file is as you want, this is just Excel trying to be helpful and failing.

Comment: csv do not save the excel column format.  They simply save the text as is.  If you reopen the csv in excel, excel does not know that you want that column to be text so it tries to convert anything that looks like a date or a number to those.  If you want to reopen the csv, you will need to IMPORT the csv not open it.  That way during the IMPORT process you can DEFINE the column as TEXT BEFORE the values are put in the column.

Comment: When you **OPEN** a csv file in excel, you are **NOT** visualizing the CSV file. Share the original CSV file. If you need to use Excel to make some alterations, you must **IMPORT** the csv file into Excel using either Power Query or the legacy import wizard. You will then be able to designate that column as **TEXT** before Excel converts it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

"SAS" is unknown to me...

Might there be means to define the export from SAS as corresponding to
`=CHAR(39)+<current-content>`? *(the result from that Excel formula is good)*

Open a CSV-file with such a field will (as always) have Excel tret it as TEXT regardless of the data that comes after the `'` *(`CHAR(39)`)*

If not possible, then use any other means; e.g. Python to massage the file, so to have the above happen.